# Cassandra write giving very slow perfomance using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, amazon-emr, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a cassandra table with around 500+ million records (In 6 nodes), now I'm trying to insert data using spark-cassandra-connector in Amazon EMR

Table Structure

```
  CREATE TABLE dmp.dmp_user_profiles_latest (
        pid text PRIMARY KEY,
        xnid int,
        day_count map<text, int>,
        first_seen map<text, timestamp>,
        last_seen map<text, timestamp>,
        usage_count map<text, int>,
        city text,
        country text,
        lid set<text>,

    )WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"NONE", "rows_per_partition":"ALL"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_kb': '256', 'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 172800
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX dmp_user_profiles_latest_app_day_count_idx ON dmp.dmp_user_profiles_latest (day_count);
CREATE INDEX dmp_user_profiles_latest_country_idx ON dmp.dmp_user_profiles_latest (country);
```

The following are my spark-submit options

```
--class com.mobi.vserv.driver.Query5kPids1
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true  
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024    
--conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=1024 
--executor-memory 1g
--executor-cores 2
--driver-memory 4g
```

But in the logs I have seen writing to Cassandra takes around 4-5 minutes for loading 2 lakh (200,000) records(while total execution time is 6+ minutes)

I have added  the following in Spark conf also

```
conf.set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows", "auto");
conf.set("spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes", "500");
conf.set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes", "100000");
conf.set("spark.cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec","1");
```

But still there is no performance improvement , also increasing the no of cores in Amazon EMR doesn't help.

Please note that In my Cassandra table we have not used any partitioning/clustering column , so could this be the reason for such slow performance.

Please Note Network speed is 30 MB PS an primary key is an Alphanumeric Values eg - a9be3eb4-751f-48ee-b593-b3f89e18622d

Cassandra.yaml

```
cluster_name: 'dmp Cluster'
num_tokens: 100
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories:
     - /data/cassandra/data
disk_failure_policy: stop
commit_failure_policy: stop

key_cache_size_in_mb:

key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
counter_cache_size_in_mb:
counter_cache_save_period: 7200
saved_caches_directory: /data/cassandra/saved_caches
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
seed_provider:
 - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
    parameters:
 - seeds: "10.142.76.97,10.182.19.301"

concurrent_reads: 256
concurrent_writes: 128
concurrent_counter_writes: 32

memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
memtable_flush_writers: 8
index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: 10.142.76.97
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: 10.23.244.172
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5
concurrent_compactors: 4
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 64
sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 500000

range_request_timeout_in_ms: 1000000

write_request_timeout_in_ms: 200000

counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 500000

cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 100000

endpoint_snitch: Ec2Snitch

dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100

dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000

dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1

request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler

server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra

client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra

internode_compression: all

inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
```

Comment: can we have your database structure?

Comment: Do you have access to the node? To see how your database is scatter across the cluster?
Maybe all your records goes to the same node (thus increasing the amount of nodes is useless)

Comment: Yes I do have access , how do I check that ? As nodetool status shows 6 nodes up and running and each of them having 100 tokens

Comment: I don't really know, I don't use Amazon EMR :/
I just wanted to know if by chance, all your pid hash fall in the same range (which would be very unfortunate)

Comment: Amazon EMR I'm using for processing, while the Cassandra is in EC2 (6 nodes)

Comment: Do you have something like an OpsCenter?

Comment: Again how do I check for PID hash weather it falls in the same range ? Do u mean a Java Hash Function  , Sorry to ask but what do u mean by OpsCenter.

Comment: What I would simply do is just look at how many data cassandra take on every nodes.
Can you give some config on Cassandra, like the partitioner and the placement strategy?

Comment: Ok so several remarks there: 1. Are your Spark workers co-located on the same machines as Cassandra process ? If no, you don't have data-locality and all the workers are streaming data on the network to reach the Cassandra nodes so it's very expensive 2. What are the hardware specs of the 6 Cassandra nodes ? CPU ? Disk type (spinning, SSD) ? Memory ? 3. What is your Cassandra config ? Can you provide a link to the `$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra.yaml` or `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` somewhere ? Usually, massive insert scenarios are stressing more CPU than disk.

Comment: Hi Im using c3.2xlarge with 8 cores  15GB memory and   2 x 80 SSD , also Cassandra and Spark workers aare on diff machines , also I will share cassandra.yaml parameters here

Comment: Hardware specs are very decent,  do you have Spark workers installed on the same machines as Cassandra process ?

Comment: Ok here is the drill : Data transport over the network is expensive whether it is one the cloud or not. So this is the first bottleneck. Second bottleneck, your driver's memory is 4G and your executors 1G for how what amount of data ? Let's say 20G, I think ! Do you see the picture now ?

Comment: No they are on different machines

Comment: Hi elishah , I'm testing with only 15 MB file (ie 2 lakh lines of data) , So I guess executor memory is enough.

Comment: So your issue may probably be there. You're generating a lot of data from Spark workers and they need to cross the network to reach Cassandra machine. To **rule out** Cassandra hardware issue, please install **dstat** and execute `dstat` for 30 secs during the insertion, from any Cassandra node. Take a screenshot of the dstat display and post it here please

Comment: Whitefret , I have edited the post with the exact table structure , As I dont know how to check for partitioner strategy.

Comment: 15 mb partitioned over 6 nodes might be an overkill, try with more data, compare and update your question

Comment: I tried with 500 MB also still the same perfomance , ie  it runs for 5+ hours.

Comment: Also , the network speed is 30 MB PS

Comment: Whitefret I have checked the cassandra.yaml file we are using this partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner

Comment: well, nothing wrong here.
The next thing I could think of is about the index, has `day_count` a lot of different value?

Comment: Yes for each record there is a different value.

Comment: I posted the cassandra.yaml in the original post

Comment: ok that's the problem.

each time you add something, it must calculate a new index, with takes a lot of time. Index are for value which don't change a lot and have a limited amount of values like countries, categories, genre...

Comment: So for update also it will change the index ?

Comment: see this link that explains it way better than me ;)
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint Whitefret , yes this seems to be a problem as day_count is a map and the geniuses here has made it an Index , so its a huge blow. So can you please suggest how to drop those indexes. As this is production environment.

Comment: Will this do the trick? http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/drop_index_r.html
however, I would consider looking at why it is an index before dropping it in prod

Comment: Exactly I'm talking to the person who designed it, but still I feel making a map an index seems (that too with all different values) should be avoided.

Comment: Ok, warn me if this didn't solve your problem

Comment: RAHUL, You can try to drop all the indices and re-insert again to see if it improves the speed. If yes then secondary index is the culprit, if not, the problem is somewhere else

Comment: @doanduyhai he can't do that in prod

Comment: Ahh didn't see that it's in production sorry ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As talked in the comment, it seems your problem comes from your index on day_count.

As seen in this [page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html), index won't be efficient if you must update them all the time, and it does when you insert a different value into day_count (which is possibly everytime).

You need to rework your database, but as this is your production environment, you can't just `DROP INDEX IF EXISTS keyspace.index_name` if this index is necessary, but you could create a secondary database using `day_count` as the primary key, or use `day_count` as an ordering index.

Comment: By the way, **IF** the issue comes from secondary index (we do not have absolute certainty unless measuring the insert rate without those indices, **measure don't guess**). One solution can be to drop the index to insert all the data into Cassandra and then recreate the index. It would mean that the application cannot query by index until the insert is finished

Comment: Hi as an update , we are not using that Index for querying , So is it ok if I drop it ? Also you said it is not efficient if its updating everytime , and it does when we insert a different value , in my case we are updating the map values(index) everytime and in some cases we are inserting a new value in the map.

Comment: Please suggest. As I need to remove the index.

Comment: @RahulKoshaley I guess you could drop it but it's hard to tell. it would be better to try it in a test environment first.

Comment: If you are sure you don't use it drop it, if it produce bug put it back again

Comment: Hi Whitefret thanks for the suggestions, but currently I'm thinking of restructuring the entire table structures and check for perfomance, as I'm more than sure by removing the index on day_Count will result in perfomance but still reluctant to touch the existing table as its in prod.

Comment: @RahulKoshaley  Then maybe you can consider doing a secondary table for it as a hotfix while working on your new model. It will improve your performance but you need to be sure your request are atomic

Comment: Hi Whitefret , Do you mean secondary table for the collection day_count ? , if yes can you suggest a structure from your experience , also for a PID(PK) there can be mutltiple Map entries. So what do you suggest ?

Comment: Sorry to deceive you but I am no expert in database design. I can only give you some advices:  
- read the doc found in datastax which gives some hindsight of how to choose variables in the partition key, and the clusterings keys
- choose carefully what Index you want
- when encountering these kind of problem when you need an index on an ever changing variable, do not hesitate to create another table as replication is cheap and it will improve your read performance.

Comment: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling

also I watched 101 and 201 tutorials there : https://academy.datastax.com/

Comment: Ok thanks , one last question is it imp to have custering/partitioning key and also Indexes ?

Comment: @RahulKoshaley Partition Key is how your data will be scatter accross the cluster. If you want to have quick reads, you need to group element which you want to access together because you read faster the less you read different partitions. For example, in my database, my partition key is a process code and a country, so all the data associated to a process and a country will be stored in the same partition

Comment: @RahulKoshaley Clustering key are useful to order you data, and for queries. You can't query with a Where clause if a field is not on the primary key or is not indexed. So either your fiel has a low cardinality and it can be an index, or like me with the filename, you need to order it to have quick access in case you are looking for a file in a where clause

Comment: Basically, it depends on the query, you need to build your data model with the query you expect and not with the data you have. One of my requirement is to do request by date which I can't with my model, that's where I am now, and I hesitate between changing the model or make multiple table

Comment: @RahulKoshaley just thought of it: with Cassandra, what you gain on read you loose on write. Secondary indexes are a good example if that